# Advice on closed question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I just posted a SO question I thought was totally pertinent, and was looking for a very specific answer. Could you give me some insight on why it was closed?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773414/general-framework-for-world-data

I can certainly understand that framework questions can elicit opinions, but in this case I'm looking for a reference to a specific framework that I haven't been able to find.

Could someone tell me how I should modify or help me reopen it, as this is a legitimate open question for me!

Comment: "What should I make for dinner?" is also a "legitimate" question. To me, the message text in the close reason is pretty clear: `We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unusual for a ♦ moderator to close a question instead of allowing the community to do it, maybe it was flagged.

No matter how nicely you phrase the question, it still falls under the category of a "shopping question". This means that you will potentially get a range of answers, most of which will be suggestions. This might be exactly what you are after, but unfortunately it doesn't make an ideal Stack Overflow question, and the answers are prone to going out of date as time passes.

Your question is one of the better shopping style ones I have seen, but the problem is that if yours (and the question style) is allowed then there will be literally hundreds of poorly worded and/or defined ones that will follow it.

Comment: So from that shopping writeup, it's specifically mentions that questions with enough specificity are relevant.  (The low light camera example.)  Ultimately, I take your point about the validity of answers going out of date though.  That said, here I'm really asking if this type of framework exists so I can research it further.  I just really haven't found anything in this ballpark, and I'm asking if something like this exists (mentioning the best candidate I've found so far and why that doesn't fit the bill).

Comment: If I could impose on a little more of your time:  What venue would you recommend would be appropriate for a question like this?  Should I take this somewhere else on the SE network (paid or not)?

Comment: Ok, will close.  If someone could point me in the right direction for tracking something like this down I'd appreciate it, but thanks for the feedback regardless.